# How to Update ElasticSearch index mapping and add multi-fields into it?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created the index with following setting and mapping:

```
PUT test

    {
        "settings": {
            "number_of_shards": 2,
            "number_of_replicas": 1
        },
        "mappings": {
            "documents": {
                "properties": {
                    "title": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "url": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "tags": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In above mapping, I have declared tags as type keyword for the exact match.and added 10 documents into it for example:

```
PUT test/documents/1
{
  "title":"John",
  "url":"/john",
  "tags":["name question","how"]
}
```

but I want to add multi-fields support for tags to support partial tags matching  so I have updated index mapping as follows:

```
PUT test/documents/_mapping
{
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "raw": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        },
        "url": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "raw": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        },
        "tags": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "fields": {
                "raw": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is this right way to updae index mapping? Can now my tags support partial matching?
Please help me into this

Answer (score 4):

Yes. That's the way to update that field. Although I'd not use `raw` as the name for the subfield. It's not the common to have `raw` as `text` type.
I'd name it something like `fulltext` for example.

Anyway, even if you update the mapping you have to reindex all the documents.

[Update by Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) will do that:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/test/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed"
```

By the way (and not related to your question) I'd use `_doc` as the type name so you will be even more ready for the removal of types in the future.